# C Program, Nothing printing in terminal

Tags: c, loops, output, getchar

I have the following c program that should print our a vertical histogram of the lengths of the words in its input.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_WORD_LENGTH     35      /* maximum word length we will support */

int main(void)
{
int i, j;                     /* counters */
int c;                        /* current character in input */
int length;                   /* length of the current word */
int lengths[MAX_WORD_LENGTH]; /* one for each possible histogram bar */
int overlong_words;           /* number of words that were too long */

for (i = 0; i < MAX_WORD_LENGTH; ++i)
    lengths[i] = 0;
overlong_words = 0;

while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n')
        while ((c = getchar()) && c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n')
            ;
    else {
        length = 1;
        while ((c = getchar()) && c != ' ' && c != '\t' && c != '\n')
            ++length;
        if (length < MAX_WORD_LENGTH)
            ++lengths[length];
        else
            ++overlong_words;
    }

printf("Histogram by Word Lengths\n");
printf("=========================\n");
for (i = 0; i < MAX_WORD_LENGTH; ++i) {
    if (lengths[i] != 0) {
        printf("%2d ", i);
        for (j = 0; j < lengths[i]; ++j)
                putchar('#');
            putchar('\n');
        }
    }
}
```

I have this compiled as a.out, at the terminal I do ./a.out, I type in a word and nothing happens. Any help? I am new to C and just trying to learn.

Comment: Properly format your code with indents and put braces on your big if's and while's. I can't follow this code at all.

Answer (score 3):

Your program doesn't print anything out until after `getchar()` returns `EOF`. That means entering a word and hitting return won't do it. You need to press `^D` on a blank line to tell your terminal emulator to close the input stream.

A quick test here seems to show that your program works. You may want to check on the order of operations in your big `&&`/`||` logic - clang gave me some warnings about `&&` within `||`.

Comment: `Ctrl+Z` for windows terminal.